# swift change view after animation

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui

i have a animation with .ontapgesture, and it works fine. so far so good.
but I want to call my next view after the animation is finished. but I don't know how. Is there an option to build in a delay while the animation runs?

```
var body: some View {
Text("test")
    .scaleEffect(x: isButtonPressed ? 1.5 : 1, y: isButtonPressed ? 1.5 : 1)
   
    .animation(Animation.linear.repeatCount(5))
    .onTapGesture {
        isButtonPressed.toggle()
        jumpToNextView.toggle()

}
}
```

Comment: This might be helpful: https://www.avanderlee.com/swiftui/withanimation-completion-callback/

Comment: Hi Raja, many thanks. I will have a look at this website!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DispatchQueue to execute the toggle of jumpToNextView after the animation.

```
Text("test")
    .scaleEffect(x: isButtonPressed ? 1.5 : 1, y: isButtonPressed ? 1.5 : 1)
    .animation(Animation.linear(duration: 0.25).repeatCount(5))
    .onTapGesture {
        isButtonPressed.toggle()
        //<< executed after 0.25 (duration) * 5 (repeat count)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.25) {
            jumpToNextView.toggle()
        }
    }
```